# Not Able to Populate Mac and IP address Values into javaobject from json using Jackson: Error :Unrecognized field not marked as ignorable

Tags: jackson, pojo

I am tring to use Jackson to populate POJO(Java Object) from incoming Json from GUI, other attributes are populated properly but the problem is only with Mac Address, L3 Ip Address and L4 source and Dest Port.

The error is:

> Unrecognized field not marked as ignorable

Any suggestions as to what I might be missing ??

```
Abc abc = null;
try {
    abc = mapper.readValue(body, Abc.class);
    System.out.println("Jackson Abc="+abc.toString());
} catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Abc is my POJO : Setting the values as

if (this.dlDst != null) {
            header.setField(HeaderType.DL_DST, HexEncode.bytesFromHexString(this.dlDst));
        }
```

Also while debugging I've found it's hitting the parameterless constructor of my POJO and the pojo object is filled as null ... but the error only says about mac address and ip address, source ports in the above example its dlDst.

Comment: Please add the source of Abc, and the json you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Your Abc class must have a matching setter method for each property. If one such method is missing, or named slightly different (casing!), you'll get this error message.